# QueryString Encryption and Related Characters Problems

Tags: vb.net, encryption, query-string, asp.net-4.0

I'm using a 64base data encryption function to Encrypt and Decrypt emil addresses sent in links and back in QueryString using :

```
Encrypt(txtEmail.Text).ToString
```

// Which generate something like this " pqM/rgLD9PSrE+Ofm4pt4kg86+1RChHD "

```
Decrypt(Request("email").ToString
```

But the Decrypt didn't work fine and returned an error "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array" until I fond that I may solve it using :

```
Decrypt(Request("email").Replace(" ", "+").ToString)
```

Since the plus sign "+" character was generating a space when call from a URL.
I also tried UrlEncode but didn't help

```
Decrypt(Server.UrlEncode(Request("email")))
```

**Now my questions is:**

1. Is this the only problem may I face with the encrypted strings?
2. Is there another way to solve the problem more  effective than I used with replace function?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: **Base64 is not encryption**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would happen if you don't generate the URL properly.

The ASP.Net `Request` accessors will automatically decode the data that you access.

However, you need to URL-data-encode your string before putting it in the querystring in the first place.

Comment: Hi SLaks, In my case, I encrypt email address before sending a URL to member email who clicks the link and then I decrypt it when reach the confirmation page. Do you mean that I have to use URL-data-encode in my sent link .. like :"xxx.aspx?query=" + Server.UrlEncode(Encrypt(EmailValue).ToString) ... Thank you

Comment: @hsobhy: Yes.  Whenever you insert data into any kind of structured format (URLs, HTML, Javascript, SQL, etc), you **always** need to correctly encode it.